# use .htaccess with php5.4 built-in server

Tags: php, .htaccess

In my development environment, I use the web built-in web server of php5.4 but it seems that .htaccess doesn't work correctly. I can't found the doc of that server. Can someone tell me if it is possible to use htaccess and mod_rewrite like apache?

Thank you very much

Comment: By default the current directory is your webroot and this webserver doesn't support `.htaccess`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As in my comment mentioned, the current directory is by default your webroot. Also this webserver doesn't support `.htaccess`.

You'll find a [good explanation](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/php-5-4-built-in-webserver) about your issues here.

> **Get the Server Running**
>
> By default, the current directory is your webroot and you can now
> request whatever files are here, and run PHP in the usual way

or

> **Routing Requests Like Apache Rewrite**
>
> One immediate feature that I was looking for was the ability to
> redirect all incoming requests to index.php, which I usually do with
> an .htaccess file. This webserver doesn't support those (although my
> good friend Josh has created something pretty close) but it does
> support a routing file.

Comment: It would be useful to quote the relevant part of the linked article here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a fan doing of this, but I have seen this done in the wild, by the software Magento:

```
/**
 * Parse .htaccess file and apply php settings to shell script
 *
 */
protected function _applyPhpVariables()
{
    $htaccess = $this->_getRootPath() . '.htaccess';
    if (file_exists($htaccess)) {
        // parse htaccess file
        $data = file_get_contents($htaccess);
        $matches = array();
        preg_match_all('#^\s+?php_value\s+([a-z_]+)\s+(.+)$#siUm', $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        if ($matches) {
            foreach ($matches as $match) {
                @ini_set($match[1], str_replace("\r", '', $match[2]));
            }
        }
        preg_match_all('#^\s+?php_flag\s+([a-z_]+)\s+(.+)$#siUm', $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        if ($matches) {
            foreach ($matches as $match) {
                @ini_set($match[1], str_replace("\r", '', $match[2]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1b7c8107492ddea9d480152bdc81908befd0795c/shell/abstract.php#L110-L134

It's meant for applying PHP settings from `.htaccess` to PHP CLI scripts, but I imagine it should work well for PHP's built-in web server as well.